# error in import statement Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase

In the import statement of `Firebase` is being highlighted red

### [image: in the import statement Firebase.. is being highlighted red]

After doing `clean and rebuild project` the error is had not been resolved. Dependencies are added in `build.gradle` but still nothing is happening
please help.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my build.gradle file.

Comment: Provide us with your buid.gradle

Comment: you likely didn't add required lib

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: i have posted my build.gradle file now

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `build.gradle`

```
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2
```

Comment: then goto file-> invalidate caches/restart and restart and clear the cache hope its help